# Trouble sizing fixed footer element to visually match content element width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to have a fixed footer at the bottom of a page where there exists a sidebar of a fixed width on the left AND the fixed footer must line up with and be the same width as a content element directly above it. The content element takes up the full width of the screen minus the width of the sidebar, minus the 35 px margin on either side of the content and minus the width of the scrollbar (when present).

I've tried for a few hours now, but the only solution I have come up with involves calc where I have to subtract the width of the sidebar and also find a way to exclude the width of the scrollbar when it is present. I'm hoping there's a better way to do this, but at this point I'm thinking there may not be.

Here is my HTML.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outside{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

.sidebar{
  display: flex; 
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
  width: 350px; 
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  display: flex; 
  flex: 1 0; 
  background-color: blue; 
  margin: 35px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: -100px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100px; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: orange; 
  margin: 0 35px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div class="outside">
        <div class="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="content">
                This div represents a chunk of scrolling content.
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The sidebar will be fixed, but that hopefully this HTML will suffice for this question.

The problem is that the footer (in yellow) needs to line up on the left and right-hand side with the blue box. Currently it *does* line up on the left side, but since `position: fixed;` removes the footer from the layout, it is actually calculating the space based on the width of the entire browser window. Is there a clean way to fix this issue without manually calculating the width of the footer myself like this? `width: calc(100% - 316px);`? This gets super tricky since when the sidebar is collapsed I need to change it to something else, like `width: calc(100% - 90px);`. And when the scrollbar displays I need to set yet a different value of `width: calc(100% - 333px);`. I'm doing an Electron app, so I only need to support Chrome scrollbars, but I guess if Google decides to make those look different it would potentially break that code.

I know that `100vw` and `100%` are both available options and that sometimes 100% *doesn't* include the scrollbar, but I've read that you can only count on that working if the fixed control isn't declared inside another element with `overflow: auto;` (or something like that). In any case, that's not working with the HTML / CSS that I have here.

I've read that others are just using Javascript to return the client width of the browser to exclude the scrollbar width. I can do that if that's my only option.

`position: sticky;` does solve most width issues I have, but introduces some of its own that aren't good. For example, sticky doesn't push the footer to the bottom of the page itself, content would have to do that, but sometimes the content will only take up a small portion of the page. In that case, the footer still needs to show at the bottom.

I think this covers all of the things I have tried. I am really appreciative of anyone that takes a bit of their time to help me better know whether I have any better options than what I've already investigated.

Comment: You answered your own question. Make the sidebar (as you said you'll do) *"fixed"* or whatever you need. Than place the footer as its own child on its bottom using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` ;)

Comment: And please.... **stop** using inline `style` attributes.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That does not fix the problem, unless I misunderstand. In our actual code (this is just a mock up) we're already doing this with the sidebar. I can't think how this would help resolve the width issue at all, but I'd love to see an example where it does help.

The inline style is just a mock up. We of course don't use it in production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized a solution I tried before that didn't work because I had a different HTML structure is actually what I should be doing now. Since we're doing `position: fixed;`, instead of margins, I should just be setting the left and right explicitly because the width will take care of itself if I do. I still have the scrollbar issue, but I think that's actually related to some other bad CSS in the DOM that I need to fix. I will update this with details of my solution once I have it fully realized.

This does mean though that when someone collapses the sidebar the layout breaks, which isn't great and would require that I create styles that are aware of the state of my sidebar. If someone has something that works better, I'd love to hear it.

-=-=-=-= UPDATE 1 -=-=-=-=

OK, I have a pretty functional version that's better than the `calc` option I was using before, and that's just to set the `bottom`, `left` and `right` all individually. If you get those numbers right, the width will be taken care of by the browser. In my situation I still had to deal with a collapsing sidebar, so I had to set the left coordinate differently when that is collapsed.

All that said, our designer okayed a change that pushed the content div all the way to the bottom of the page even when there was no content to display. This made it even more trivial as it opened it up for us to use `position: sticky;` instead, which is by far the best option.

-=-=-=-= UPDATE 2 -=-=-=-=

The scrollbar issue is also gone, it was unrelated to my other code.

Here is the full solution with `left;` and `right;`.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outside{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

.sidebar{
  display: flex; 
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
  width: 350px; 
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  display: flex; 
  flex: 1 0; 
  background-color: blue; 
  margin: 35px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: -100px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100px; 
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange; 
  left: 385px;
  right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div class="outside">
        <div class="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="content">
                This div represents a chunk of scrolling content.
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
                <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```